# IRestResponse could not be found

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have restsharp 107.1.2 loaded via nuget target framework is .net 6.0.  The following code claims that IRestResponse reference is missing, though I feel like I'm following pretty close to the RestSharp documentation.  What am I missing?

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using System.Text;



static void Main()
{

    
    String url = "https://www.invoicecloud.com/api/v1/biller/status/";

    //Set up the RestClient
    var client = new RestClient(url);

    //Store the generated API from the biller portal
    String GeneratedAPIKey = "SomeKey=";

    //Convert genrated API key to Base64
    String encodedAPIKey = encoding(GeneratedAPIKey);

    //HTTPBasicAuthentication will take a username and a password
    //Here we use your API key as the username and leave the password with ""
    client.Authenticator =  new HttpBasicAuthenticator(encodedAPIKey, "");

  


    //Get the request
    var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.Get);

    //Get the response

   // var response = client.ExecuteGetAsync(request);

    IRestResponse reponse = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As per the documentation (https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107) ...

`The IRestResponse interface is deprecated. You get an instance of RestResponse or RestResponse<T> in return.`

https://restsharp.dev/v107/#deprecated-interfaces

Again, according to the documentation ...

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.myorg.com");

var request = new RestRequest()
    .AddQueryParameter("foo", "bar")
    .AddJsonBody(someObject);

var response = await client.PostAsync<MyResponse>(request, cancellationToken);
```

... as an example.

Comment: Note: One may still utilize the execute method using RestSharp with the latest stable release v.108.03    RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Comment: Just for future reference for people, this was example was very useful, i got it working for  blizzard APIs easily enough:

Comment: using RestSharp;
var client = new RestClient("https://oauth.battle.net/token");
var request = new RestRequest()
    .AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
    .AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<ID>&client_secret=<SECRET>", ParameterType.RequestBody);
CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
var response = new RestResponse();
response = await client.PostAsync(request, cancellationToken);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);