# The type or namespace name "IRestResponse" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, access-token, restsharp

I have a problem with `IRestResponse` in the below:

```
public async Task<CezanneToken> GetAccessToken()
{
    var client = new RestClient(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenUrl"]);
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Method = Method.Post;
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"] + "&client_secret=" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"] + "", ParameterType.RequestBody);

    IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
    string serStatus = ((RestResponseBase)response).Content;
    CezanneToken details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CezanneToken>(serStatus);
    string Token = details.access_token;
    
    return details;
}
```

`IRestResponse` throws

> The type or namespace name "IRestResponse" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> I cannot make it work. IntelliSense suggest to go with `RestResponse`> instead of `IRestResponse`.

But when I go with `RestResponse` I get `Bad Request` on the response.

The code sample above is "translated" from Visual Basic but it works just fine in VB. I don't know if the problem with the `Bad Request` comes from using `RestResponse` but I assume `IRestResponse` is needed just as in VB.

I've also seen people using `IRestResponse` but it just doesn't work for me. I have the `using RestSharp;` but do I need something else as well?

Comment: Maybe you can read the RestSharp docs.

Comment: Issue also mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921065/irestresponse-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Install the older version of the RestSharp NuGet package (<=106.15).

The latest major version of RestSharp has breaking changes, which are described in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Downrev to 106.15 worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

According the RestSharp docs  https://restsharp.dev/v107/#recommended-usage

> The IRestResponse interface is deprecated. You get an instance of
> RestResponse in return.

After just updating the nuget package to the latest stable release v.108.03, **Execute** request works as intended, without the compiler error.

```
RestResponse response = _client.Execute(request);
```

OR

```
RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 2):

As `IRestResponse` is deprecated, using of `RestResponse` is suggested. This should fix the error.

```
RestResponse response = _client.Execute(request);
```